# Problems I had with my first flutter project:

Tags: flutter, android-studio

It first time working in flutter project in Android Studio I have this problem ,these picture in command prompt and flutter project explain problem;

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run `flutter doctor -v` in the command line, then follow it's instructions. If the command fails to run completely, check Flutter is correctly installed and add the correct path to the global PATH (or equivalent in your OS).

Comment: I would recommend `flutter clean`, followed by `flutter pub get`.  If this doesn't work, try reinstalling your flutter installation.